# How to serialize and deserialize a list of objects using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I am getting an error while deserializing an array of objects.

ans int the below expression is a `List<Restaurant>` type

```
String json = obj.writeValueAsString(ans);
```

I am getting error in the below line

```
List<Restaurant> all= Arrays.asList(obj.readValue(reslistjson,Restaurant[].class));
```

The error -
Cannot deserialize instance of `com.crio.qeats.dto.Restaurant[]` out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: (String)"{"restaurantId":"12","name":"A2B","city":"Electronic City","imageUrl":"www.google.com","latitude":20.015,"longitude":30.015,"opensAt":"18:00","closesAt":"23:00","attributes":["Tamil","South Indian"]}"; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: Seems like your JSON represents an object, and you're trying to deserialize it as an array.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it is a list of objects
What changes should i make ?

Comment: Impossible to tell without you providing a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you show us what your `reslistjson` looks like? so we can figure out why it is not deserializing

Comment: There is obviously a problem with your JSON, why don't you serialize your array of Restaurants and see how it should like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON input in your example is an object not an array.
For your JSON data, this would work:

```
List<Restaurant> all= Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(json,Restaurant.class));
```

A JSON like this is an array of objects and your original code would work:

```
String json = "[{..data1 goes here....}, {..data2 goes here....}]";
List<Restaurant> all= Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(json,Restaurant[].class));
```